# Why would you put an explicit "return;" at the end of a void function?

Tags: c++, return, void

Is there has any different by putting or not putting return in the the last line of function?

```
void InputClass::KeyDown(unsigned int input)
{
    // If a key is pressed then save that state in the key array
    m_keys[input] = true;
    return;
}
```

Comment: There is no difference. You have an extra line of code though.

Comment: I don't understand why there are so many answers especially when they all say the same thing. I of course think mine is the best (and I was first to answer) but think Shafik answer is the only one that could be better (than mine)

Comment: Someone is being payed by the line

Comment: There are already so many answers that I can't dare post one more, but _I'd like to elaborate just a bit_. As said it makes no difference here, _but_ I can imagine it be enforced by some "corporate coding standard". Consider `int f() { /* no return */ }`, it causes a `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void`, but some (lazy) programmers just ignore warnings ("it compiles, it's ok"), so a convention may require to have a `return` as the last line of _every_ function (even if empty). (Moreover, `return;` in `int f()` would cause an _error_, as `return 1;` in `void g()`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no difference !

***return*** in void functions is used to exit early on certain conditions.

*Ex*:

```
void f(bool cond)
{
    // do stuff here
    if(cond)
        return;
    // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is functionally no difference in your example, if we look at the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.6.3` *The return statement paragraph 2* says:

> A **return statement with neither an expression nor a braced-init-list can be used only in functions that do not return a value,** that is, a function with the return type void, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4). [...] **Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value;** this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular code, No. But usually if you want to have an early return from the function based on a condition then use `return`.

```
void InputClass::KeyDown(unsigned int input)
{
    // If a key is pressed then save that state in the key array
    m_keys[input] = true;
    if(someCondition) //early return
       return;
   //continue with the rest of function 
   //.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it serves absolutely no purpose - it also won't cause any problems (e.g. no extra code is generated assuming the compiler has at least some optimisation ablities).

There is of course a purpose to putting a `return` in the middle of a void function, so that some later part of the function is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

No Difference, in your example,but if you want to an earlier return from the function in case,it is useful

Answer (score 1):

`return` in `void` functions has multiple roles:

1. prematurely end function execution (e.g Algorithm finished, preconditions are not met)
2. in certain cases you design the algorithm such that in 85% of the cases will end sooner. (thus executing faster) leaving the other 15% of the case go after that return (thus running slower for some rare race conditions.
3. similar to a `goto end`.

Comment: The question is specifically about having return in last line of the function!

Answer (score 0):

In this case NOTHING. In other cases it might be because code is after the return statement and the author wanted to have it 'dead' for a little while. It should be deleted afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

No, they are same things.

Use return; when you want to exit function.