# Using return; in recursion functions

Tags: c++, return

```
#include <stdio>
using std::cout;
void CountDown(int N) {
  if(N == 0) {
    return;
  }
  cout << N;
  CountDown(N-1);  
  //return;
}
```

In the code the output I get when return is commented is same as when not commented.

What I want to ask is whether it makes a difference if I use a `return;` statement at the end of the function (since it would implicitly return to the function, which called it, at the end of the braces)?

Another question:
What if had a function with a return type instead of void here.
I tried it with a function. The value was wrong.But there was no compiler error.
So using simply a `return;` makes no difference right? Except when I want to prematurely end the function right?

Comment: It makes no difference whether you put `return;` at the end of a function returning `void`. This has nothing to do with recursion, it is always true.

Comment: Mmm. In that code, the last `return;` is never reached, isn't it? But in any case, that sentence is no necessary in `void` functions.

Comment: See [what is the purpose of return in the void function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18638286/1708801)

Comment: Re updated question, falling off the end of a value returning function is undefined behavior see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20614282/1708801) ... because it is undefined behavior no diagnostic is required.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I didn't get it.What does undefined behaviour mean.And how does it affect the program? I mean its not a compiler error right?

Comment: Undefined behavior is bad, it basically means unpredictable behavior, see the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: If there was no compiler error when you left out the value return your compiler is misbehaving, or you were ignoring its warnings.

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you check this out please :[link](http://geeksquiz.com/binary-search/).The binary search program in it,first one. If I remove the `return` statements from the recursive function calls to binarySearch again the program gives a wrong answer but there is no compiler error. I am using Codeblocks IDE.

Answer (score 4):

For `void` return functions, no it doesn't make a difference.  However, if the function is expected to return anything *but* `void`, then you'll need to include a valid `return` for all code paths.

Comment: There is no code path that would reach beyond the call to `CountDown(N-1)`

Comment: well, your answer is of course still correct, I just thought one might misunderstand it

Comment: @tobi303 why not? I mean when (n==0) case would be done and that function will return to the function  CountDown(1) then the return; statement would be executed right?After the calling CountDown(0) part.

Comment: hm yes you are right. I faster in writing than thinking, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

At the end of a `void` function control is automatically returned to the calling function so you do not need a `return;` at the end.  `return` in a void function is used to exit the function before it normally would like in your if statement.

If you have a function that is supposed to return a value and does not then that is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).